# Semi-transparent gradients become a solid color on Kitkat

Tags: android, gradient, android-drawable, android-4.4-kitkat

When I run my app on a kitkat device then all semi-transparent gradients in my app become a solid color. Unfortunately I can't post any screenshots due to app being in development.

Examples:

- semi-transparent grey gradient on a light background becomes solid black
- semi-transparent grey gradient on a black background becomes solid white

This problem is not reproducible on Lollipop and above. My min sdk is 19, compile and target sdks are 23.

Has anyone ever experienced similar problem?

IMPORTANT EDIT:

When I background my app and come back to it then everything is rendered correctly.

Comment: Are your check your theme?

Comment: Please see my important edit.

Comment: how are you creating those gradients? by `new GradientDrawable`? `new LinearGradient`?

Comment: These are gradients from XML file and gradients inside nine patch png files.

Comment: something unknown is drawn behind, verify this by: create a `new GradientDrawable`, draw it over a `Bitmap`, `compress` that `Bitmap` on the file system and see the final file using paint / gimp / whatever

Comment: and, did you make sure `GradientDrawable` works fine?

Comment: Yes, they work fine. It something strange with the whole app: circular progress bar becomes rectangular and yellow instead of grey-ish, lists' end animations are also really strange.

Comment: I used setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); on all these problematic views and the problem is gone, but now everything is not smooth, it's very laggy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the gradient for background through code

```
 GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                new int[]{0xFF151D2A, 0xFF591E22, 0xFF901E1E}); // Gradient Color Codes
        gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(0f);                   // Setting Corner Radius
        gradientDrawable.setGradientRadius(5);               // Setting Graidnet Radius
        gradientDrawable.setGradientCenter(5, 5);
        gradientDrawable.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT);
        mDrawerLayout.setBackground(gradientDrawable);
```